# Relation between Sonarqube and build tools

Tags: maven, sonarqube, devops

This might be a basic question to most people that have experience with these tools, but I recently went to an interview where the interviewer asked me "What's Sonaqube", "What's Maven" which I basically just defined based on various Google searches prior to the interview, but then the killer questions, "**What's the relation between Sonarqube and Build automation tools**?" "How does "**Sonarqube work with Maven**", "**Why do we use Sonarqube with build automation tools**"..... And I literally froze and couldn't answer them and died a bit inside on my career ambitions as a Junior dev!

So here I am, for anyone to enlighten me on these killer questions for any other interviews to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Maven

Maven is a build automation tool used primarily for Java projects.

It would be incredible, that a current team, develop java applications without maven. Without maven, a lot of tasks would be necessary:

- store the java libraries close to source code, increasing the disk size of each java project.
- search new libraries in google and manually download them.
- compile manually your jars, wars, ears, etc
- artifacts version would be a nightmare
- invoke unit test manually
- manually integration with external platforms like SonarQube or servers like tomcat, widfly, etc
- and dozens of tasks related to build, test and deploy for java applications.

## Sonarqube

SonarQube is an open-source platform for continuous inspection of code quality. This platform helps to detect bad practices like : empty try catch, nullpointer, conditional mistakes, etc

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/sonarqube-null-detection.png
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/sonarqube-logger.png
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/sonarqube-issues-tracking-bugs.png

## What's the relation between Sonarqube and Build automation tools? Why do we use Sonarqube with build automation tools?

Build tools are used to automate tasks related to software life cycle, devops, continuous delivery/deployment, etc. One of this stages is called **build**. In this stage it would be great and highly recommended, use SonarQube to inspect source code with aim to improve quality, detect bugs & issues and decrease the technical doubt. This is the relationship between build tools and Sonar

## How does Sonarqube work with Maven?

Basically you could generate the reports of our project on SonarQube Dashboard using a maven command , previously configured.

Read this post to a fast review of Maven & Sonar Integration : https://blog.knoldus.com/integrate-maven-project-sonarqube/

Comment: Downvote? Why? Is this information wrong or outdated?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sonarqube is one of the code quality tools we use in the build chain. It helps is in calculating the technical debt of the code, amount of the code covered with the unit test cases, Bugs, vulnerabilities and basically it helps in building a clean code.

1. You can customize the rules for each and every project which are boarded to Sonarqube with varied set of conventions.
2. In the build chain, Sonarqube plays a vital role for teams which are agile and wants to find out most of the vulnerabilities before it hit even the Dev instances. So it is integrated with Continous integration tools like Teamcity, Jenkins etc... and are triggered as one of the build step before the deployment stage.
3. It is used by both the developers and also the management to see the improvements which are made between each release and even between individual builds.
4. Sonar code analysis could defined as a task in Maven and we can have a separate sonar.properties file to list out the parameters for publishing the results in a common portal. Also one can specify parameters from the build configuration to enable the report to be generated in the CI tool which is used by the project.

This is a handy guide to know more - https://www.infobip.com/en/engineering/improving-code-quality-with-sonarqube

Answer (score 1):

1. SonarQube is a code quality plugin that you can use to inspect your
   code.
2. You can add the SonarQube plugin in your maven build to analyze your code.
3. To show the results in your build server (hudson/jenkins/bamboo), you also need the SonarQube integration plugin for your build server.
4. Next to that you can also use a quality gate in the build server to let your 
   build fail if the code does not meet the specified quality requirements.